# How can I recover a lost chrome devtools window with an unsaved snippet?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I had a devtools window open with a lengthy snippet (unsaved) in the sources. Somewhere between tabbing around and adjusting window size to test responsiveness, I lost the window I was working in.

The window must still open somewhere because when I try to reopen devtools on that page I get an alert saying: "DevTools has unsaved changes that will be permanently lost. Are you sure you want to leave this page?"

Does anybody know how I can regain access to this window without losing the code in the snippet?

Comment: I've had this problem before, and just a minute ago again. I know I shouldn't rely on snippets, but sometimes I forget where I'm coding, and add lots of lines to a snippet, and then bam, I close the tab and it's gone.

Comment: I just learned you shouldn't store anything there either. I just lost a few snippets, even after they saved when chrome updated....